# Adding an euler angle to a Quaternion

Tags: c#, math, quaternions, euler-angles

I want to add an euler angle to an existing quaternion. Here is what i got:

```
Quaternion oldTransform = transform.Rotation;

float YawRotation = mouseDiff.x *  RotationSpeed;
Quaternion YawRotationQuaternion = new Quaternion();
YawRotationQuaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle (0, 1, 0, YawRotation);

float PitchRotation = mouseDiff.y * RotationSpeed;
Quaternion PitchRotationQuaternion = new Quaternion();
PitchRotationQuaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle ( 1, 0, 0, PitchRotation);

Quaternion result = oldTransform * YawRotationQuaternion * PitchRotationQuaternion;
transform.Rotation = result;
```

I want to have only yaw and pitch rotation. The old transform has this property. My euler angles I add to it are also only pitch and yaw rotations. What happens when i multiply it is that the rotation that oldTransform describes introduces a roll rotation.

Then i tried:

```
Quaternion result = YawRotationQuaternion * oldTransform * PitchRotationQuaternion;
```

This introduces no roll rotation. This option is even worse as it has a gimbal lock when oldTransform rotates the yaw-axis onto the pitch-axis.

Now what I could imagine is that one gets the old yaw and pitch rotation from the oldTransform and modifies the yaw and pitch-axis so that they are not (0,1,0) and (1,0,0) anymore. The problem here is that when I extract the euler angles from the quaternion I get gimbal locks as well.

So how do you add an euler angle of a specific axis to a quaternion?

Comment: Suddenly, I feel dumb.

Comment: I am sorry, that was not my intention...

Comment: :)  Of course not, it's not your fault.  Good question.

Comment: Gimbal lock is what happens when you use pitch/yaw/roll or euler angles. You can't get around this. That's one reason why quaternions are used. What are you actually trying?

Comment: This explains your problem quite nicely: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8980/euler-angles-and-gimbal-lock

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Solution:*

Change the order of your transformations.

```
Quaternion result = PitchRotationQuaternion * oldTransform * YawRotationQuaternion;
```

---

*Explanation:*

You have an object with a local reference frame.  I'll say that **+x_o** is toward the object's right, **-z_o** is "forward" and **+y_o** is "up" with respect to the object.  The object exists in the world's reference frame.  The world has its own axes: **(x_w,y_w,z_w)** with **+y_w** being the world's up.  When the object changes orientation, you want it to *pitch* (rotate around **x_o**), and *yaw* (rotate around **y_w**).

In your code, you create two quaternions.  The way you apply them represents rotations around **x_w**, and **y_w**.  If there is any *yaw* already applied to the transformation, then **x_o** is no longer aligned with **x_w**; consequently, you'll get some *roll*. Fortunately, for the transformations you're applying, gimbal lock isn't a problem.  Gimbal lock would be manifest here by the fact that if you *pitch* by 90 degrees, *yaw* and *roll* become the same thing. But your not using *roll*; so it doesn't matter.

Your transform can always be represented as a rotation around **x_w** followed by a rotation around **y_w**.  Putting the new "*pitch quaternion*" on the left side of the old transform adds it to the other accumulated *pitch*.  Keeping the "*yaw quaternion*" on the right adds it to the accumulated *yaw*.  So if you were to represent the final quaternion as a bunch or multiplications, it would be a string of pure rotations around **x_w** followed by a string of rotations around **y_w**.  As long as the object starts of with **x_o** parallel to **x_w**, this does what you want.

Comment: Works ty! Took me a while to find out. Now I have the problem that I need to invert the order of the rotations somewhere. But this is different topic. The question is hereby solved :)