# Is there a way to get Euler angle orders in nalgebra or another Rust library?

Tags: rust, rotation, nalgebra

I'm trying to convert raw quaternion values to Euler angles in order zyx. I'm trying to use `nalgebra` rotations to convert, but the in-built conversion only gives angles in order xyz. Is there a way to convert from quat to zyx or from xyz to zyx? Or an alternative library that can do the same conversion?

Here's the function I'm currently using for conversion:

```rust
pub fn raw_quaternion_to_euler(w: f32, x: f32, y: f32, z: f32) -> (f32, f32, f32) {
    let unit_quat = UnitQuaternion::from_quaternion(nalgebra::Quaternion::from_vector([w, x, y, z]));
    unit_quat.euler_angles()
}
```

Comment: Are you just asking to reverse a tuple or something?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297374/adding-an-euler-angle-to-a-quaternion

Comment: Is [doing it yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles#Quaternion_to_Euler_angles_(in_3-2-1_sequence)_conversion) a valid option?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work out a way of doing this using a different library from nalgebra called [quaternion-core](https://crates.io/crates/quaternion-core). It was really simple to use and did exactly what I was asking for in this question.